# Manually remove inactive CCParticleSystem from scene?

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, objective-c

When using particle systems that have a lifetime, with `CCParticleSystem` and its derived classes, should I manually remove the finished systems from their parent nodes once the particle animations are complete? Or this is done automatically? I don't want to leave dead particle systems in my scene, for obvious reasons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`CCParticleSystemBase` has an `autoRemoveOnFinish` property. The name is self explanatory. This property is `NO` by default. So should be set to `YES` on creation for particles that have a finite lifetime.